# EC2 C Family instances slowing down over time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got some simulations running on a c4.large Ec2 instance on Amazon AWS. These simulations have iterations which I was able to complete in around 1.5 hours when I first loaded the instance. I was getting around 35-40% CPU utilisation. But after some time the same iteration now takes around 2.75 hours to complete. The CPU utilisation has dropped down to around 18-20%. I have tried the following remedies -

1. Re-deployed the application on the instance.
2. Restarted the application servers
3. Rebuilt the environment

None of options made any real difference. The only thing I haven't tried is creating a new environment and deploying that. I'll try that after writing this post. But I wanted to see if others have been having the same issue and they've done or what they can think of regarding my issue.

I was told in another question I'd asked ([How to get consistent CPU utilization on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979806/how-to-get-consistent-cpu-utilization-on-aws/47980841?noredirect=1#comment82939679_47980841)) that running instances from the C and M family would allow me to achieve consistent performance. But I can't seem to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your simulation very I/O intensive? You may be exhausting the I/O burst limit of the underlying EBS volumes.

Comment: Hey mate .. I've been monitoring the RDS Write IOPS rate as well. I've set up a basic db.t2.micro instance with an allocated size of 50GB. According to the documentation I should get a base Write IOPS rate of 150. And currently isn't 40/s .. When the application was running at it's fastest the IOPS rate was round 85/s .. So each iteration does do a lot of writing into the database and a little bit of reading .. I found a BurstBalance metric for the two EBS volumes I'm currently running .. they both show 100% ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Upon looking at some more RDS metrics, I was able to find a metric for CPUCreditBalance on the RDS instance and it has come all the way down. It was high when I first started the simulation. But now it's zero. So the bottleneck wasn't the c4.large EC2 instance. It seems the bottleneck is the RDS instance which is throttling the CPU Utilisation.

Comment: This seems correct, and it explains both of your observations.  While your application is kept "busy, waiting" on a response from the database, it should not be using very much of its own CPU.  Similarly, when an RDS instance is starved for CPU resources, it won't be able to generate enough IO requests to saturate its own disk capacity.